# How can I check whether a Freebase MID is a schema in freebase or not?

Tags: freebase

I want to filter out all the triples which has a schema in its head or tail. So I want to check check a mid is a schema or not. But can somebody teach me how to do this?

Thank you so much..

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of the type of thing you want to exclude or include?  It's difficult to understand from your description what you're trying to achieve and I can think of at least a couple different plausible possibilities.

Comment: [schema](http://www.freebase.com/music/group_membership?schema=)  like this, which has a type flag in its page's top left corner. And entity like this, [entity](http://www.freebase.com/m/026t6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects or nodes in the graph which are part of the type system have a `/type/object/type` of `/type/type`.  Other schema components such as domains (groups of types) and properties also have their own types (`/type/domain` and `/type/property`, respectively).

If what you really want is all entities however, you're probably better off looking objects which have the type `/common/topic`.  This will exclude not only components of the schema, but also mediator nodes (aka CVTs) like https://www.freebase.com/m/0kpxvh?links= which are used to describe complex relationships.

Whether an inclusive or exclusive filtering strategy would work best really depends on what you're trying to accomplish, which I'm not sure I fully understand.